# How to write a Firebase Storage rule to allow read/write to a group?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-security, firebase-storage

I am trying to write rule for Firebase storage. On storage different groups will store and retrieve images and hence I cannot use User based security by using UID as match path.

In Firebase storage docs there is a example for case like mine in which data can be secured by using file metadata. So I am not able to understand how should I add different people's IDs to group ID key of metadata. Here is Firebase sample code for such case.

```
match /{groupId}/{imageId} {
        allow read: if resource.metadata.owner == request.auth.token.groupId;
        allow write: if request.auth.token.groupId == groupId;
      }
```

But in my case there maybe many users for a group. So how should I add all IDs to `metadata.owner`of a image? Can I use Comma separated string of UIDs?

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/firebase-talk/77i9CRlwg88/lf2DZsx9AQAJ;context-place=forum/firebase-talk has info on this

Comment: @MikeMcDonald so without custom auth tokens it is not possible? But thread suggestion of cross security rules is best, please add it to firebase. Because I have my database with all ids under some groupID node,but we cannot access that data in storage rules. for custom tokens I need to use a server of Cloud functions,isn't it?

Comment: Cloud Functions is probably the easiest way to do this, yes.